# context:component -scan not working

Tags: java, spring

This is my code:

```
package foo.bar;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class SpringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        AbstractApplicationContext kontekst = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        kontekst.registerShutdownHook();
        Shape trojkat = (Shape) kontekst.getBean("Circle");
        trojkat.draw();
    }
}
```

Circle.class

```
package foo.bar;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Circle implements Shape{

        private Point center;

        @Override
        public void draw() {
                System.out.println("Drawin circle");
                System.out.println("the point is x:"+center.getX()+", y="+center.getY());

        }
        public Point getCenter() {
                return center;
        }

        @Resource
        public void setCenter(Point center) {
                this.center = center;
        }
        @PostConstruct
        public void initalizeCircle(){
                System.out.println("init of circle");
        }
        @PreDestroy
        public void destroyCricle(){
                System.out.println("destroying circle");
        }

}
```

Spring.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?      
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar"/>

   <bean id="pointA" class="foo.bar.Point">
       <qualifier value="test"/>
           <property name="x" value="0"/>
           <property name="y" value="0"/>
   </bean>

    <bean id="pointB" class="foo.bar.Point">
        <property name="x" value="60"/>
        <property name="y" value="40"/>
    </bean>    

    <bean id="center" class="foo.bar.Point">
        <property name="x" value="20"/>
        <property name="y" value="30"/>
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

I have tried in many ways, changing the name of source.

When I change in xml to

```xml
<bean id="Circle" class="foo.bar.Circle">
</bean>
```

Eveyrthing is fine , but I want to know why is that, I am new to Spring. I was looking for similar topics on stackoverflow but i can't resolve my problem.

Comment: Try getting bean by type(i.e. Circle.class) not by name (likely its name will be `circle`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the name of your bean will be the name of the class starting with lowercase. So, you don't have a `"Circle"` bean, you have a `"circle"` bean. Try this:

```
Shape trojkat = (Shape) kontekst.getBean("circle");
```